# How to specify test browser in jsperf?

Tags: javascript, browser, performance-testing, jsperf

I found lots of test cases in jsperf could run in lots of browser and show result in browserscope.

But when I setup a test, the test could only run in my own browser verson.

How can I run my testcase in all version browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsPerf doesn’t automatically run the tests in all browsers for you. You’re supposed to run the test in all the browsers you care about. That will populate the Browserscope result tables.

Answer (score 2):

If you use something in a part of the test that isn't supported by a browser, then JSPerf will continue with the next test (should there be one) upon failure.
However should you have some setup-function that is executed before any of the tests start to run and you use a browser(-version) specific method, then obviously no tests will run on other browsers. To solve that you'd need some other setup-function (using a shim/polyfill etc.)

As far as I'm aware of, you can't set a jsPerf testcase to test only one specific browser, but you *can* define a specific Browserscope result filter:

From [jsPerf FAQ - Result filters](http://jsperf.com/faq#result-filters):

> **Can I predefine a specific Browserscope result filter when linking to a test case?**
>   Yes. For example, if you want to only show results for mobile browsers by default, you could append `#filterBy=mobile` to the test case’s URL. The other result filters are `popular` (the default), `all`, `desktop`, `major`, `minor`, and `prerelease`.

From [jsPerf FAQ - Browserscope](http://jsperf.com/faq#browserscope):

> **The Browserscope results look different from the ones I’m getting. Why?**
>       Browserscope returns the highest known result for each test. Because each test has a margin of error, we submit the results minus the margin or error (the lower limit of the confidence interval, i.e. the lowest suspected value) to Browserscope.

Also, when using a batch of browsers for testing, one can do that unattended:

From [jsPerf FAQ - autorun](http://jsperf.com/faq#autorun):

> **I don’t like clicking buttons. Can I make the tests run automatically after opening a page?**
>   Sure, just append `#run` to the URL of the test case, e.g.
>   http://jsperf.com/document-getelementbyid#run.

Comment: Why the downvote? I answered every possible interpretation of the extremely vague question.

Comment: I agree, no need to downvote. The question was a bit vage, and this answer contains lots of good info!